# Yii many_many relation not working all the time

Tags: activerecord, yii

I've been following [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/285/accessing-data-in-a-join-table-with-the-related-models/) tutorial to set up a many-many relationship between a business model and a categories model.

My tables are:

```
business[id (PK),name,date,...]
business_category[businessID (FK to business.id), categoryID (FK to category.ID)]
category[id (PK), name, date,...]
```

In my business model I've got

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'categories'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Category',
                            'business_category(categoryID,businessID)'),
    );
}
```

and in my category model I've got

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'businesses'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Business',
                            'business_category(categoryID,businessID)'),
    );
}
```

When I pass to a CListView widget

```
'dataProvider'=>new CActiveDataProvider('Business', array(
                                'data'=>$model->businesses)),
```

where `$model` is a category model, I can then loop through the categories of each business normally: `foreach($data->categories as $category)`

When I have `$model = $this->loadModel($id)` though, `$model->categories` does not have any results.

What could be wrong?

Comment: have you tried to skip loadModel() and do $model=new YOURMODELNAME::model()->findByPk($pk) instead?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've done a var_dump $model and ensured that's it's not NULL and you do actually have a model returned from loadModel(), I suspect this may be due to the order of your columns in the businesses relation. Try:

Category Model:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'businesses'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Business',
                            'business_category(businessID,categoryID)'), // Swapped order of columns
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad... I was returning multiple records from a query and thats why `$model->categories` was not working.